How to count non blank cells when a certain range has written values
Simple question: How do I count how many non-blank cells from column A also have at least one "X" to their right?



A
B
C
D
E




data 01
X





data 02

X
X



data 03






data 04






data 05

X




data 06






data 07



X


data 08
X





data 09






data 10


X



data 11






data 12

X




data 13






data 14


X



data 15






data 16
X





data 17

X
X
X


data 18






data 19

X




data 20







The formula I'm trying is {=CountA(If(CountA(B:E)>0, A:A))} and it's an ArrayFormula.
The result should be 11 (the number of shaded rows), however it's evaluating 20 (the total number of rows).
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks
EDIT:
I know to workaround this problem. For instance, I could count the number of X's on each row and then count those results. But I want to do this with a single formula, if it's possible.
Also, I don't want to use the countifs formula because, in the real problem, the number of columns with X's is a LOT bigger.

Did you consider concatenating all cells in one row and check if the length is zero? (I believe you can use =CONCAT() and =TEXTJOIN() functions)

I tried but it gave me the same result. Thanks anyway. :)

You could try this using MMULT()


=SUM(--(MMULT(N(B1:E20="X"),{1;1;1;1})>0))


To make it more readable could use the following note that this formula works with Excel 2021+ onwards,
=LET(
     _Data, A1:E20,
     _Ncolumns, DROP(_Data,,1),
     _Columns, COLUMNS(_Ncolumns),
     SUM(--(MMULT(N(_Ncolumns="X"),SEQUENCE(_Columns)^0)>0))) 


If Column A has to be validated as well then:
=SUM(--(MMULT(N((B1:E20="X")*(A1:A20<>"")),{1;1;1;1})>0))


Or, Dynamic approach:
=LET(
     _Data, A1:E20,
     _ColA, TAKE(_Data,,1),
     _Ncolumns, DROP(_Data,,1),
     _Columns, COLUMNS(_Ncolumns),
     SUM(--(MMULT(N((_Ncolumns="X")*(_ColA<>"")),SEQUENCE(_Columns)^0)>0)))



You could try:

Formula in F1:
=SUM(--BYROW(B1:E20="x",OR))


Fun alternative without ETA LAMBDA:
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(TOCOL(IFS(B1:E20="x",A1:A20),3)))

